# angular 5 show error while ng build --prod

Tags: angular, angular5

During `ng build --prod`, I see the error occurs as:

> Cannot determine the module for class AdminLoginComponent in
>   /var/www/html/ngAngular/src/app/admin-login/admin-login.component.ts!
>   Add AdminLoginComponent to the NgModule to fix it.

My app.module.ts is includes the below codes:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AdminLoginComponent} from './admin/admin-login/admin-login.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from './register/register.component';
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    AdminLoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AdminModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuardService, AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Is anything I need to add to somewhere?

Comment: check if you have components imported but not used, delete the imports

Comment: Have you made 2 components with the same name?

Comment: You have an unused component but have created it and it resides in your structure dueing compile time

Comment: what does `admin-login.component.ts` look like?

Comment: @ArunRajR - Yes, previously there was a component. I copied it and paste the same folder in another folder named admin. This issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have 2 components with the same name. So, can you remove or rename it and try again?